# как вывести alert со словом madrid,при этом написать в строке поиска barcelona

Tags: javascript, alert

нужна помощь с одним задание,много гуглил,но решения не нашёл,помню точночто в книге проходил,но к сожалению забыл.
Суть задания, нужно в поле поиска ввести одно слово нажать найти и чтобы тебе выдало alert с другим
Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как пример: js и html

```js
let search = document.getElementById("search");
let subButton = document.getElementById("subButton");

subButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert('Тут что хотим получить в алерте')
});
```

```html
<input id="search" class= "search" type="text">
<input id="subButton" class="button" type="button" value="Поехали">
```